# Detailed documentation on arm intrinsics support versions

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I am trying to build an infrastructure (and database) so that people can detect the available SIMD intrinsics without connecting to the actual hardware.

It is extremely hard (if ever possible) to get the proper hardware for all those ARM versions and try each intrinsic on them, so I am looking into the possibility of reusing existing database or documentation.

Are there any detailed documentation/database on supported arm SIMD intrinsics for each version
(https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm/versions)

The arm handbook (https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/)  listed all supported instruction for a broader category, but it seems to be no way to check which instructions/intrinsic are supported on a certain version of ARM supports.

Please let me know if you have anything in mind that can help.

Comment: normally you use the cpuid registers, understand that each instance of a core at a chip vendor can be modified.  you can buy a core with floating point but choose not to implement, buy a core with cache, buy a core with x, buy a core with y...you really need to use the cpuid assuming the chip vendor has strapped those correctly and/or your data base needs to be chip and stepping.

Comment: I think the 'ARMv5' only had some FMAC instructions and 'Q' saturation.  There was no 'SIMD' instructions.  Some ARMv6 had neon.  The page you reference allows you to select the architecture as a filter.  I don't understand why this is not enough?

Comment: The problem is that when a certain version of ARM has neon or hellium, it might NOT have the whole set of neon, just some parts of it. Also, that page has only 4 architectures in the filter, which is likely not enough for what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the answer to your question is in the xml files at: https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/exploration-tools where instructions have their sub-architectures. Alternatively in the [Arm ARM](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest).

But sub-architecture doesn't entirely map to what cores actually support as they may support different parts of the architecture. Technical Reference Manuals (TRMs) are available on https://developer.arm.com/ for Arm-designed cores, which will say what parts of the architecture are supported. Other chips will need to be described by their designers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It doesn't seem to have a centralized place for the info. I guess I will just have to look into different part of the manuals...